# lightweight dialog plugin that doesn't require css

Tags: javascript, dialog

I'm looking for a lightweight dialog plugin that doesn't require css.
I need it for a userscript, which means I can't include a css file

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just copy and past the css code into the file and wrap it with `style` tags.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. where am I supposed to put it? like at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply set the innerHTML of a style tag created via javascript. In this way you obtain an inlined stylesheet.

E.g.

```
var styleText = "body { background-color: red } div { color: lime }";
var styleBlock = document.createElement("style");
styleBlock.innerHTML = styleText;
document.head.appendChild(styleBlock);
```

Another idea is to use a dataURI of a css file:

E.g.

```
var linkEl = document.createElement("link");
linkEl.href = "data:text/css;base64,Ym9keSB7IGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6YmxhY2sgfQo=";
linkEl.rel = "stylesheet";
linkEl.type = "text/css";
document.head.appendChild(linkEl);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could dynamically inject a css file from a remote domain, which is what disqus does, for example.

```
var link = document.createElement('link')
link.rel = 'stylesheet'
link.href = 'http://yourhost.com/your.css'
```

You'd make to make sure your css has low chance of clashing with your user site's styles by restricting the styles using id or class names.

Comment: yeah I thought about doing that, but injects are not allowed by the siteowner